# Highcharts fold/unfold waterfall

Tags: highcharts, fold, waterfall, unfold

I use Highcharts watefall (and stacked waterfall for multiple measures) and it is very powerfull.
I would like to get a better render with a dynamic fold/unfold.
In the following example : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/4x1ndpjr/
I would all california/colorado/dc columns hidden by default (only Subtotals & Total columns visible) and when mouse overed a Subtotal/Total column, the dedicated california/colorado/dc columns are shown.

I think I can use

> ```
>   plotOptions: {
> column: {
>   point: {
>     events: {
>       mouseOver: function() {
>       ...
>       }
>       mouseOut: function() {
>       ...
>       }
>     }}}}
> ```

But how to hide columns that are not isIntermediateSum and display only the ones concerned by the isIntermediateSum overed ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, How would you like to handle categories? Do you want to show/hide only columns or also categories?

Comment: Hi, the best would be to hide columns & categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use breaks for x-axis and dynamically update chart depending on hovered point. Example:

```
function generateBreaks(hoveredX) {
    const breaks = [];

    for (let i = 3; i < 12; i += 4) {
        if (hoveredX !== i) {
            breaks.push({
                breakSize: 0,
                from: i - 0.5 - 3,
                to: i - 0.5
            });
        }
    }

    return breaks;
};

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        ...,
        breaks: generateBreaks()
    },
    ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mpf4egwn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I need. The result is here : https://jsfiddle.net/vegaelce/etmx94vu/
But I have another small problem to fix : how to hide the stack labels of each hidden columns (and display them when the columns is shown) ?

Comment: Hi @vegaelce, You need to check if a stack label is in a break. Please check this possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ebptsjuc/